# Can't boot into Kali after an update. Still learning how to parse these logs...can anyone lend a set of eyes and help me sort this out?

Tags: linux, boot, debian, recovery, journalctl

I recently did a:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

And have been unable to boot since.

Fortunately, I can boot into recovery mode but I am having trouble diagnosing the issue. I've pulled the logs from both the unsuccessful boot and the successful recovery boot but I am too new at this to be able to pick up any glaring red flags. If anyone has a moment to spare, would you be willing to point me in the right direction?

The full `journalctl -b` log for the unsuccessful boot [can be found here.](https://pastebin.com/Qm38CFgJ) And the full `journalctl -b` log for the successful boot into recovery mode [can be found here.](https://pastebin.com/WQ9iSpq3)

I see some stuff  near the end of the "successful" recovery boot that sounds unpromising to the beginner, a lot of `last-resort fallback`'s and such. I could be looking in the entirely wrong area though, I am not too familiar with the boot process.

Comment: Are there any files related to LightDM in /var/log?

Comment: Start up and interrupt the boot so as to start in a terminal.   ............   Try   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove

Comment: @u1686_grawity Yes, there are several logs related to LightDM in /vat/log. As follows:

```lightdm.log```      ```seat0-greeter.log```      ```x-0.log```      ```x-1.log```
```lightdm.log.old```  ```seat0-greeter.log.old```  ```x-0.log.old```  ```x-1.log.old```

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at the newest lightdm.log and maybe other files that are from the same time – your system log shows that lightdm itself is starting, but then it's not launching X to display the graphical logon screen for some reason.